# Getting compilation errors "lvalue required" for program

Tags: math, division, lvalue, prime-factoring

I need to make a program that counts the amount of times a number is divisible by 2 or 3 and if it is factorable by 2 or 3. the code i have is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int input, two, three;
    int counter;
    counter = 0;
    three = 0;
    cout << "Please enter your natural number." << endl;
    cin >> input;
    if (input%2 == 0 && input%3 == 0)
    {
        cout << "Your number is divisible by 2 and 3" << endl;
    }
    else if (input % 2 == 0 && input % 3 != 0)
    {
        cout << "Your number is divisible by 2" << endl;
    }
    else //(input %2 != 0 && input %3 == 0)
    {
        cout << "Your number is divisible by 3" << endl;
    }
    while (input % 2 == 0)
    {
        counter++;

    }
    while (input % 3 == 0)
    {
        three++;

    }
    cout << "Amount of times divisible by 2: " << counter << endl;
    cout << "Amount of times divisible by 3: " << three << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Im getting errors like the one mentioned up there about the lvalue not being mentioned. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't use `if`-conditions properly.

- Use `==` to check equality instead as `=` is for value assignment.
- Use `&&` to check `and` instead of `;`.

You need to change

```
if (input%2 = 0; input%3 = 0)
```

to

```
if (input%2 == 0 && input%3 == 0)
```

And change others accordingly.

---

**Updated:** for your updated code, you need also to change

```
else (input %2 != 0 && input %3 == 0)
```

to

```
else // (input %2 != 0 && input %3 == 0)
```

because `else` doesn't need any check conditions.

Comment: okay i fixed those mistakes. thank you!

however i am still getting this error:
prime23.cpp:22:2: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
  {

Comment: any idea about this error though?

prime23.cpp:22:2: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
  {

Comment: @user3242614 Can you share your updated code? Maybe in Ideone.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!! sorry for all the questions but i have just one more!

for my while loops i cant get them to stop looping. when i run the program in terminal the loop just never ends. I figured since the reminder would eventually not = 0 the while loop would stop. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: @user3242614 This is easy, you need to change all `while` to `if` as you only need to check it once, not a loop.

Comment: Yeah but the problem lies with numbers that can be divided by 2 or 3 more than once. For example the number 12. If i used an if statement wouldnt it only run once, so i never find out how many times its divisible by 2?